# Django-tastypie pass request.user to custom save method

Tags: python, django, tastypie

Since my model's custom save method takes request.user as an argument I'm unable to do POST/PUT requests.

```
TypeError at /api/obsadmin/observation/23
save() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

I'm using SessionAuthentication() and have included the CSRF token.

Here's the relevant model part:

```
def save(self, user, owner=None, *args, **kwargs):
    self.updated_by = user.id
    super(ObsModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

And the resource:

```
class ObservationResource2(ModelResource):

comments = fields.ToManyField(CommentResource2, 'comments', full=True, null=True)

class Meta:
    queryset = Observation.objects.filter(is_verified=True)
    authentication = SessionAuthentication()
    authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
    resource_name = 'observation'
    always_return_data = True
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could override the default `save()` method on your `ModelResource` subclass. Looking at the [default implementation](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/v0.9.14/tastypie/resources.py#L2236-L2258) shows that `save()` is called with a bundle object which has both the request and the object to be saved.

Unfortunately, there's no easy way to change this without copying most of that code because changing a Django model's `save()` signature is fairly uncommon. You might be able to do something like this, although I'd recommend testing it carefully:

```py
from functools import partial

try:
    old_save = bundle.obj.save
    bundle.obj.save = partial(old_save, user=bundle.request.user)
    return super(FooResource, self).save(bundle)
finally:
    bundle.obj.save = old_save
```

References:

- obj_create: [docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#id11) [source](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/v0.9.14/tastypie/resources.py#L2094-L2105)
- obj_update: [docs](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#id12) [source](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/v0.9.14/tastypie/resources.py#L2146-L2166)
- save: [source](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/v0.9.14/tastypie/resources.py#L2236-L2258)

Answer (score 5):

I've just achieved this same end goal by using the built-in `hydrate` methods to modify the data prior to saving. The current request is available in `bundle.request` inside the `hydrate` methods. See the docs [here](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/resources.html#hydrate).

I have a `Friend` model exposed via `FriendResource` that I want to link to the creating Django user via a `user` ForeignKey field.

My example Resource code:

```
class FriendResource(ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        queryset = Friend.objects.all()
        resource_name = 'friend'
        excludes = ['slug',]
        authentication = SessionAuthentication()
        authorization = DjangoAuthorization()
        always_return_data = True

    def get_object_list(self, request):
        return super(FriendResource, self).get_object_list(request).filter(user=request.user)

    def hydrate(self, bundle):
        bundle.obj.user = bundle.request.user
        return bundle
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I'm no longer using Tastypie (we switched to DRF), but thanks for answering. I'm sure it will be helpful to someone.

Comment: Thank you so much! This mechanism is somewhat confusing and docs are scarce, I've wasted an hour trying to figure it out...